# Execution plan show that clustered index query costs more than non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM TB_TMP_TR GROUP BY ACCNO
SELECT SUM(AMT) FROM TB_TMP_TR2 GROUP BY ACCNO
```

The only different thing is `TB_TMP_TR` has `ACC` as clustered index and `TB_TMP_TR2` has `ACC` as non-clustered index.

Execution plan show that the 1st is take 65% and 2nd take 35% (batch relative)

but with

```
SELECT * FROM TB_TMP_TR WHERE ACCNO = @acc
SELECT * FROM TB_TMP_TR2 WHERE ACCNO = @acc
```

the 1st is faster

I'm wondering why ?

Comment: What **datatype** is `ACCNO` in your tables?? In your second example - does `TB_TMP_TR2` have some other column defined as clustering index? If so: what column?? What datatype is that column??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A covering non-clustered index will likely be narrower than the clustered index, since the clustered index must include *all* columns. Being narrower it means it has fewer pages, which means fewer reads (both physical and logical). Hence, it will be faster. **Covering** being the key word.

Please run the two queries with

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```